# Read Cookie invalid with php

Tags: php, cookies

I can not read a cookie with php. Do not understand why.

It was created by this command: `setcookie('cookie', '1', time() + 10000000);`

The cookie is well established, I have looked in different browsers

The attempt by a read: `echo $_COOKIE['cookie'];` nothing prints and with `var_dump($_COOKIE['cookie']` print NULL

It could be that the server will not let me read them?

Comment: Is the cookie set as secure, and you're accessing the page using straight http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tired to set the `$_COOKIE["cookie"]` to a variable, and then made a echo on it, ex: `$cookie = $_COOKIE["cookie"]; 
echo $cookie;` Has happened to me a few times that it won't display the way you try to.

And of course, like @Kai Mattern said, you need the path

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: You did not specify a path. Please check the cookie path in your browser and see if the default path hinders you to read the cookie.

A cookie with default set in `yourdomain/somepath/page.php` cannot be read by `yourdomain/someotherpath/page.php`.

Quick check would be to set the cookie path as `/`